# Передача и вывод значений ArrayList в SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Подскажите как передать и вывести по отдельности значения ArrayList в SpringBoot, сейчас пробую так, но ничего не получается ?

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController
{
    @GetMapping("/greeting")

    public String greeting()
    {
        return "greeting";
    }
    @PostMapping("calc")
    public String calc (
            @RequestParam Double sizeCredit,
            @RequestParam Double sizePayment,
            @RequestParam Double creditPeriod,
            @RequestParam Integer paymentType,
            @RequestParam String startDate,
            @RequestParam Double rate,


            Map<String, Object> model )
    {
        Enter enter = new Enter(sizeCredit, sizePayment, creditPeriod, paymentType, startDate, rate);
        List<String> exit = enter.Count();
        for(String i:exit)
        {
            for(String j:i.split(";"))
            {
                model.put("j", j);
            }


        }
        /*model.put("exit", exit);*/
        return "calc";
    }

}
```

В качестве шаблонизатора использую мусташ, вывожу так {{ j }}, но значения не выводятся...

Comment: `ничего не получается` будьте конкретнее, что пытаетесь, что получаете, что ожидаете получить.

Comment: Начал изучать Springboot, пишу приложение, пользователь вводит данные, данные обрабатываются и складываются через ";" в ArrayList<String<, мне необходимо вернуть элементы list разделенные ";" пользователю, причем ввиде таблицы.Есть ли метод foeach,split в мусташ инфы не нашел, вот и решил разбить свой list в контроллере и вывести каждый элемент, но видимо это все работает иначе...